# Curse through a List of Groupings to build a Hierarchical Data Set

Tags: c#, loops

I have two classes.. `Item` and `ItemSet`. An `ItemSet` can be a parent or child to another `ItemSet` and stores this in a property called sets and is of type `List<ItemSet>`. Further more, `ItemSet` has an anther property in which it can hold a list of type `Item`. There is a method `Add()` on ItemSet that will allow us to add either a ItemSet or individual Items to it.

**ItemSetClass**

```
Public Class ItemSet
{
    Public List<ItemSet> Sets {get; set;}
    Public List<Item> Items {get; Set;}
}
```

Here is where my question comes in. I have some functionality that allows for the user to group data into these sets which ultimately specifies what set will be parents and children etc.. The groups are based upon columns in the database and valid values.

I have a method that currently produces a dictionary of the groups with their respective valid values. `Dictionary<string,List<object>> GroupDictionary`

So that a value in the dictionary looks like this:

`{Group1Name,[Group1Value1,Group1Value2,Group1Value3]},`

`{Group2Name,[Group2Value1,Group2Value2,Group2Value3]},`

`{Group3Name,[Group3Value1,Group3Value2,Group3Value3]},`

I would like to be able to iteterate through this list so that i can build the sets to represent the appropriate groups. Such that a tree representation of the Sets would look like...

```
Group1Value1
    Group2Value1
        Group3Value1
        Group3Value2
        Group3Value3
    Group2Value2
        Group3Value1
        Group3Value2
        Group3Value3
    Group2Value3
        Group3Value1
        Group3Value2
        Group3Value3
Group1Value2
    Group2Value1
        Group3Value1
        Group3Value2
        Group3Value3
    Group2Value2
        Group3Value1
        Group3Value2
        Group3Value3
    Group2Value3
        Group3Value1
        Group3Value2
        Group3Value3
```

The idea here is that the individual items here will be kept at the lowest group level (in this case group 3) and will be filtered by the characteristics of its parent groups.

I can seem to get my head warped around the proper way to iterate through this as it will require iterating through the groups dictionary multiple times to build the relevant hierarchy.

This is what I have so far.

```
List<string> keyList = GroupDict.Keys.ToList<string>();
        var t = 0;
        ItemSet currentItemSet = new ItemSet();
        List<object> currentGroupValues = new List<object>();
        foreach (var key in keyList)
        {
            currentGroupValues = GroupDict[key];
            foreach (var value in currentGroupValues)
            {
                //Build new ItemSet
                ItemSet thisSet = new ItemSet();
                thisSet.DisplayText = value.ToString();
                currentWellSet.Add(thisSet);
                //if(lowest level) {currentWellSet.Add(items)}
                currentWellSet = thisSet;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you only have two levels?  Usually a recursive algorithm is best approach.  It also looks like you have a pivot table and could add results into a datatable with each group being a set of columns.

Comment: It can have any number of levels.

Comment: What would an example of a recursive algorithm be?

Comment: Your input dictionary doesn't seem to have a parent-child association so I do not see how it can be done with the data you provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get hierarchical data from a database it would look like this :

[image]

You would then query the database and get a DataTable.  I built a datatable from the data you provided in code below and then recursively put the data from the table into your recursive structure.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;


namespace ConsoleApplication31
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Group", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Parent", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Child", typeof(string));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Group1Name", null, "Group1Value1" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Group1Name", "Group1Value1", "Group2Value1" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Group1Name", "Group2Value1", "Group3Value1" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Group1Name", "Group2Value1", "Group3Value2" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Group1Name", "Group2Value1", "Group3Value3" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Group1Name", "Group1Value1", "Group2Value2" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Group1Name", "Group2Value2", "Group3Value1" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Group1Name", "Group2Value2", "Group3Value2" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Group1Name", "Group2Value2", "Group3Value3" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Group1Name", "Group1Value1", "Group2Value3" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Group1Name", "Group2Value3", "Group3Value1" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Group1Name", "Group2Value3", "Group3Value2" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Group1Name", "Group2Value3", "Group3Value3" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Group2Name", null, "Group1Value2" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Group2Name", "Group1Value2", "Group2Value1" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Group2Name", "Group2Value1", "Group3Value1" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Group2Name", "Group2Value1", "Group3Value2" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Group2Name", "Group2Value1", "Group3Value3" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Group2Name", "Group1Value2", "Group2Value2" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Group2Name", "Group2Value2", "Group3Value1" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Group2Name", "Group2Value2", "Group3Value2" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Group2Name", "Group2Value2", "Group3Value3" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Group2Name", "Group1Value2", "Group2Value3" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Group2Name", "Group2Value3", "Group3Value1" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Group2Name", "Group2Value3", "Group3Value2" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Group2Name", "Group2Value3", "Group3Value3" });

            new ItemSet(dt);
        }
    }
    public class ItemSet
    {
        public static Dictionary<string, ItemSet> GroupDictionary = new Dictionary<string, ItemSet>();

        public string name { get; set; }
        public List<ItemSet> sets { get; set; }
        public DataRow items { get; set; }


        public ItemSet() { }
        public ItemSet(DataTable dt)
        {
            var groups = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("Group")).ToList();

            foreach(var group in groups)
            {
                ItemSet root = new ItemSet();
                ItemSet.GroupDictionary.Add(group.Key, root);
                RecursiveAdd(root, group.ToList());
            }

        }
        public void RecursiveAdd(ItemSet parent, List<DataRow> rows)
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in rows.Where(x => x.Field<string>("Parent") == parent.name))
            {
                ItemSet newItemSet = new ItemSet();
                newItemSet.name = (string)row["Child"];
                newItemSet.items = row;
                if (parent.sets == null) parent.sets = new List<ItemSet>();
                parent.sets.Add(newItemSet);

                RecursiveAdd(newItemSet, rows);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated code to use the dictionary as per your request.